# Accessing super class in JNI

Tags: java, inheritance, java-native-interface

I've got the following setup with a base class storing a pointer eventually set from JNI

```
class Struct {
    private long ptr;
    long c_ptr() { return ptr; }
}

class NativeInterface {
    static native void somefunc(Struct st);
    ...
}
```

Then a particular Struct that will be passed to NativeInterface:somefunc that needs to be able to access it's `ptr` field. My question is how to pass the super of `SomeStruct` to the native interface? Should it be like this or with a cast?

```
class SomeStruct extends Struct {
    void somefunc() {
        NativeInterface.somefunc(super);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the usual steps: get a field ID via JNI introspection on the Struct class, then get/set its value providing the SomeStruct instance as the object argument.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a cast or any need to use `super` here. Just pass `this`, as `SomeStruct` inherits from `Struct`, it can be passed to any function that accepts `Struct`.

```
NativeInterface.somefunc(this);
```